# installing the php apache module enable sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.3

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I am trying install libapache2-mod-php7.3 on my ubuntu server 16.04.

I am getting below error

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7.3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libapache2-mod-php7.3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libapache2-mod-php7.3'
```

Please help me install the libapache2 module on my server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get install php7.3 php7.3-cli php7.3-mysql php7.3-gd php7.3-imagick php7.3-recode php7.3-tidy php7.3-xmlrpc php7.3-common php7.3-curl php7.3-mbstring php7.3-xml php7.3-bcmath php7.3-bz2 php7.3-intl php7.3-json php7.3-readline php7.3-zip

sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.3

sudo a2enmod php7.3
```

after successfully installing, execute :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

FYI, I recommended you use the latest PHP or switch to the LTS version.

You can find out on https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: I had tried your installation code, but not working

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3-bz2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3-bz2'
E: Unable to locate package php7.3-intl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3-intl'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3-intl'
E: Unable to locate package php7.3-zip
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3-zip'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3-zip'

Comment: have you add repository? `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

Comment: yes. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update and tried this: 
sudo apt-get install php7.3 php7.3-cli php7.3-mysql php7.3-gd php7.3-imagick php7.3-recode php7.3-tidy php7.3-xmlrpc php7.3-common php7.3-curl php7.3-mbstring php7.3-xml php7.3-bcmath php7.3-bz2 php7.3-intl php7.3-json php7.3-readline php7.3-zip
but not working E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3-bz2' E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3-bz2' E: Unable to locate package php7.3-intl E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3-intl' E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3-intl'

Comment: Did you just copy and paste all of the code? FYI, you need to execute 1 by 1, then execute another installation